# Convergence of an alternating series constructed from a divergent series.

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $a_n$ is a positive sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$. Does the alternating series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_n+1}\right)
$$
converge?

The sequence $b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_n+1}$ is clearly positive and tending to $0$, but not decreasing. Can it still be proven that it converges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are counter-examples. Make $b_n$ large for odd $n$ compared to making $b_n$ small for even $n. $ Then your sum will tend to $-\infty.$ For example, take

$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
 \log n&\text{if}\, n \text{ odd}\\
 2^n&\text{if}\, n \text{ even}.\\
\end{cases}
$

Answer (score 4):

Counter-example: Take any divergent alternating series $\sum  \frac  {(-1)^{n}} {b_n}$ with $b_n >0$ and $b_n \to \infty$. Take $a_n=\frac {-1+\sqrt{1+4b_n}} 2$. [Note that $a_n(a_n+1)=b_n$].